# Mysql Query Optimization

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have two tables : table1 has 4lacs (400,000) records and other have 100 records.

I am trying following query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id as id 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.f_id = t1.id 
              AND  t1.action = 0;
```

I am using MYISAM Engine. t1.id and t2.f_id are same and indexed.

this query is taking 30 secs. Is there any way to make it faster.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to have an index on `table1.id`, `table1.action` and `table2.f_id`, and assuming no other indexes live on either table that are causing performance issues, this should be closer to optimal:

```
SELECT
     DISTINCT t1.id AS id
FROM
     table1 AS t1
     JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.f_id = t1.id
WHERE
     t1.action = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Set one index on `t1.action,t1.id` and another one on `t2.f_id`.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to add an index on `table1` that covers `id` and `action` together.

Introducing `distinct` into the query is going to slow it down as well.